# Is it idiomatic to use the expression "in tune with" in everyday speaking?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

My sister lost one of my books somewhere in the house a few days ago. Then I asked her to get it back. I guess she didn't even start searching. So, I explained why that book is so important to me, then I asked

> Are you in tune with me?

I am aware that "in tune with" means "having a good understanding".

Is it idiomatic to use the expression "in tune with" in everyday speaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In tune with" is idiomatic in everyday language, but it's not quite right for the context you're trying to use it in.

It's idiomatically used to express positive feelings about being well understood or having a connection with someone.

> "We were so in tune with each other, we didn't even need to talk about what we were cooking."

It's rarely used in a question, and I've never heard it in a direct question from one person to another.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Thank you. Btw, what should I say in the context in my OP?